# URLEncoder for integer value

Tags: java, url-encoding

`int a=50;`

How do I encode this using **URLEncoder**?

For strings we do

```
String value=URLEncoder.encoder("SomeStringValye",this.encoding);
```

Comment: why do you need to encode an int?

Comment: Wombat is right ... you know, you can turn an int into a String pretty easily ...

Comment: so you are saying i should convert the int value to string and then encode it ? or encoding an integer value is not advisable ?

Comment: The number `50` is the string `"50"` and since digits, `-`, and `.` are not special characters in URLs, you don't need to encode numbers. Encoding will do nothing, so it doesn't hurt. Remember, a URL is a string, so any value you want must be formatted as a string first, then encoded to escape special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer numbers in the URL are not an issue.  You need not URL encode it. 
So in your case, simply  construct a url by concatenating as follows

```
String s = "www.xyz.com/?id=" +1;
```

If you have some special characters in your url parameter like space,  ;, then you have to url encode the parameter value

```
URLEncoder.encode(
"urlParameterString",
java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString() )
```

If you still want to pass the integer to the URL encoder method,  simply make your integer as a string e.g., 10+""

Comment: Why use string concatenation of two string literals? --- Remove that `'`. --- You *may* also encode the string-formatted number. Did you mean "must"?